# Exclude specific area for long tap recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a method that add button on top-left of my collection view cell, and longPress recognizer. The problem is, when i set longPressRecognizer minimumPressDuration to something like 0.0001, i cant tap a button, because, instead of tapping button activates longPressRecognizer method. Please take a look:

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];

[[RACObserve(self, shouldEdit) deliverOnMainThread] subscribeNext:^(id x) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    if (self.shouldEdit){

        self.layout.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.1;

        int ind = indexPath.row;
        NSLog(@"1 blk called");
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:button];

    [button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.left.equalTo(cell.mas_left).with.offset(0);
        make.top.equalTo(cell.mas_top).with.offset(0);
        make.width.height.equalTo(@(20));

    }];

    }
```

I use reactive cocoa and masonry, but this actually doesn't matter, what i want is exclude button area from area, that i can use for `longGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.layout.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.1;

you can use self.myview.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.1; and in myview don't place button in myview.by this you can able to tap button